# Google Wavenet voice not getting right pronunciation for words - No, Know, Snow

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to synthesize the voice using google wavenet. Most of the time, words No, Know, Snow when used without context, comes out, ending with "r" sound. Like Nor, for No, Knowr for know, and Snowr for Snow. 
How to correct this pronunciation?

Sample code:

```
    voice[i] = {
      languageCode: 'en-IN',
      name: 'en-IN-Wavenet-B'
    } //ssmlGender: 'INDIAN MALE'
```

String value = ' First word starting from S,   Left to right is snow.  '

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your case using the python client library for text-to-speech [1] and the quickstart.py script from python-docs-samples [1] using the following configuration inside the script:

```
    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
            language_code='en-IN',
            name = 'en-IN-Wavenet-B',
            ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE)
```

The result was good and I didn't noticed the "r" sound you mentioned. I also leave here a quickstart from google cloud official documentation that may help you [3].

I hope it works now.

[1] https://googleapis.dev/python/texttospeech/latest/index.html

[2] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/texttospeech/cloud-client

[3] https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Problem is specific and I can share audio if required. I am using node.js platform.

Comment: Regarding your description it was a bit hard to help you with your issue without approaching it generally. If you can elaborate your description I will be able to help you further. It would be nice to have the audio and a code snippet of the configuration you're using. Also it would be nice if you can explain the use case and anything you consider that helps troubleshooting.